# Outlook doesn't recognize padding. Any solutions that don't use tables?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I have an email that uses a colored text box at the bottom.

The problem is that Outlook doesn't recognize the padding, and the text looks bad squeezed in so tight. It looks great with web-based emails clients.

I've tried using a table instead, and Outlook will recognize the padding in a table, but then you end up with other problems, like Gmail and Yahoo ignoring certain things. I've concluded that tables are not the way to go...

Has anyone had any success replicating padding in Outlook without using tables? Right now, I've resigned myself to the following code, which looks good everywhere except Outlook:

```
<div style="background-color: #D5ECFA; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <b>Header</b><br>
    Paragraph 1............<br><br> 
    Paragraph 2.........<br><br> 
    Paragraph 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a nested `<div>` and push the outer margin of it against the parent:

```
<div style="background-color: #D5ECFA; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
   <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
     <b>Header</b><br>
     <p>Paragraph 1............</p>
     <p>Paragraph 2.........</p>
     <p>Paragraph 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tested this here: http://info.contactology.com/email-view
and it looks pretty close to what you have

Comment: Outlook still ignores the padding in this example. The goal is to ensure the text is not squeezed up against the blue box.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
```

Comment: As far as I know, `padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` will have the exact same effect as `padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;`. So this doesn't answer the question.